# I want a camera that displays a wider picture when the player is facing that direction unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

hi everyone I make 2D platformer games and the camera I use now always makes the player in the middle. I want my camera to show the front of the player wider.

```c#
public Transform target;
Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;
public float smoothTime = 0.3f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Vector3 targetPos = target.position;
    targetPos.z = transform.position.z;

    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position, targetPos, ref velocity, smoothTime);       
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the `targetPos` in the according direction e.g. using

```c#
// Adjust this via the inspector
public float Offset = 1;

// Depending on your setup you might have to change "forward" to "right" or "up"
Vector3 targetPos = target.position + target.forward * Offset;
targetPos.z = transform.position.z;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a float variable `public float offset = 10.0f`. Subtract offset value from your targetPos.z as such: `targetPos.z=transform.position.z - offset;` 
Note that the value of offset is something you have to experiment with to get right. Advisably, make the offset variable public, that way you can play the game in unity editor, play with the variable till its okay, copy the value of offset, stop the game the change the value of offset in your code to the new value. Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Orthographic camera projection, you should change the viewport Size of the Camera.

You can update this value by code : Camera.main.orthographicSize = myNewSize;

Put a smaller value to zoom in, and a larger value to zoom out.
The value represent the half-screen projection on the vertical axis.

It's mean that a value of 0.5 will make a 1m cube fit the screen.

[image: Orthographic size of 0.5]